# How to call user-defined function in RcppParallel?

Tags: c++, r, parallel-processing, rcpp

Inspired by the artical http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/parallel-distance-matrix/, I try to use RcppParallel to run brute-force search in high-dimensional parametric space for backtesting using multithreads. I am stuck in how to call a self-defined function in the `struct` part. The idea is like this:

First, create a parametric matrix `NumericMatrix params_mat` in R first, and use the backtesting data with `List, NumericVector, CharacterVector` datatype, such as `List Data_1, NumericVector Data_2, CharacterVector Data_3, ...`, which are static for each parametric scenario `params_vec` (Note that it is the row of `params_mat`).

Next, define the backtesting function that output a vector that consisting 3 key variables to evaluate  the strategy performance.

Here is an example of my `params_mat` and `Backtesting_Fun` that can be run in R and Rcpp, respectively.

```
//[[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix data_frame_rcpp(const Rcpp::List& list_params) 
{
  NumericMatrix res = list_params[0];
  return res;
}

# R codes to generate params_mat
params <- expand.grid (x_1=seq(1,100,1), x_2=seq(3,100,2), ..., x_n=seq(4,200,1));                           
list_params = list(ts(params));
tmp_params_data = data_frame_rcpp(list_params);                                              
params_mat = matrix(tmp_params_data, ncol = ncol(tmp_params_data), dimnames = NULL); 
params_vec = params_mat[ii,];

# User-defined Rcpp codes for backtesting
NumericVector Backtesting_Fun (List Data_1, NumericVector Data_2, CharacterVector Data_3, ..., NumericVector params_vec)
{
  // Main function parts to run backtesting for each params_vec scenario.
  ... etc

  // save 3 key result variables together with each params_vec (just a simple illustration).
  NumericVector res = NumericVector::create(params_vec[0],...,params_vec[size-1],
                                            key_1, key_2, key_3); 
  return res;
}
```

Certainly we need to rewrite/modify the original Rcpp `Backtesting_Fun` with RVector/RMatrix types, and then use the following `RcppParallel`codes to call `Backtesting_Fun` in `struct Backtest_parallel`:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppParallel)]]
#include <RcppParallel.h>
using namespace RcppParallel;

RVector<double> Backtesting_Fun (const RVector<double> Data_1, const RVector<double> Data_2, 
                                const RVector<string> Data_3,..., const RVector<double> params_vec)
{
   // Main function parts to run backtesting for each params_vec scenario.
   ... etc;

   // save 3 key result variables together with each params_vec
   ... etc; 

   return res;
}

struct Backtest_parallel : public Worker 
{       
   // input matrix to read from
   const RVector<List> Data_1;
   const RVector<double> Data_2;
   const RVector<string> Data_3;
   ...
   const RMatrix<double> params_mat;

   // output matrix to write to
   RMatrix<double> rmat;

   // initialize from Rcpp input and output matrixes (the RMatrix class
   // can be automatically converted to from the Rcpp matrix type)
   Backtest_parallel(const List Data_1, const NumericVector Data_2, 
   const CharacterVector Data_3, ..., const NumericMatrix params_mat)
      : Data_1(Data_1), Data_2(Data_2), Data_3(Data_3), ..., params_mat(params_mat) {}

   // function call operator that work for the specified range (begin/end)
   void operator()(std::size_t begin, std::size_t end) 
   {
      for (std::size_t ii = begin; ii < end; i++) 
      {
         // params rows that we will operate on
         RMatrix<double>::Row params_row = params_mat.row(ii);

         // Run the backtesting function defined above
         RVector<double> res = Backtesting_Fun(Data_1, Data_2, ..., params_row)
         for (std::size_t jj = 0; jj < res.length(); jj++) 
         {
            // write to output matrix
            rmat(ii,jj) = res[jj];
         }
      }
   }
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix rcpp_parallel_backtest(List Data_1, NumericVector Data_2, CharacterVector Data_3,
                                     ..., NumericMatrix params_mat) 
{      
   // allocate the matrix we will return
   NumericMatrix rmat(params_mat.nrow(), params_mat.nrow()+3);

   // create the worker
   Backtest_parallel backtest_parallel(Data_1, Date_2, ..., params_mat);

   // call it with parallelFor
   parallelFor(0, rmat.nrow(), backtest_parallel);

   return rmat;
}
```

Here are my questions:

1. Can `RVector` contains `List` datatype, or is there any specific container in `RcppParallel` to contain `List`;
2. In the `Backtesting_Fun`, the input should be `RVector/RMatrix` types, does that mean we really need to convert the orginal Rcpp main codes with `NumericVector` into `RVector`?

Or is there any better way to do parallel computing for my case in RcppParallel? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:

1. I look at the other examples regarding RcppPararrel in http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/parallel-matrix-transform/, http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/parallel-inner-product/, the common idea in `struct operator()`is to use pointers to manipulate the data input for `operator()`, so is there any way to build a user defined function in my case with pointer inputs?
2. If the above way doesn't work, is it feasible to use `wrap` to convert `RVector/RMatrix` back into Rcpp datatype, i.e., `NumericVector..` in `operator()` so that the input types of user-defined function `Backtesting_Fun` can remain unchanged.

Comment: You will probably be more likely to get an answer if you provide a smaller, complete (no `...`s in your functions) example.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @nrussell, I will update the question with simple and exact example soon

Answer (score 6):

I think I may find an alternative way to solve this question: The keys are to use a thread safe accessors to contain variables within the `struct`, and remain `RVector` / `RMatrix` in the outside main function so that the `parallelFor` can work fine, which is the most important part in this parallel algo. Here are my ways:

1. **Get rid of `List` datatype**: Instead, we can convert the `List` variable by using `NumericVector` / `NumericMatrix` container and record its corresponding index so that the subvector/submatrix will point the same elements as it was as a list's element.
2. **Convert `RVector` / `RMatrix` into `arma::vec` / `arma::mat`**: As mentioned in [RcppParallel Github](http://rcppcore.github.io/RcppParallel/), `C++ Armadillo` are thread-safe in struct's operator. Here, I modify the example given in [Parallel Distance Matrix Calculation with RcppParallel](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/parallel-distance-matrix/) by using this idea, which nearly remains the same test speed.

   ```
   struct JsDistance : public Worker
   {
     const RMatrix<double> tmp_MAT;  // input matrix to read from
     RMatrix<double> tmp_rmat;       // output matrix to write to
     std::size_t row_size, col_size;

     // Convert global input/output into RMatrix/RVector type
     JsDistance(const NumericMatrix& matrix_input, NumericMatrix& matrix_output, 
                std::size_t row_size, std::size_t col_size)
       : tmp_MAT(matrix_input), tmp_rmat(matrix_output), row_size(row_size), col_size(col_size) {}

     // convert RVector/RMatrix into arma type for Rcpp function
     // and the follwing arma data will be shared in parallel computing
     arma::mat convert()
     {
       RMatrix<double> tmp_mat = tmp_MAT;
       arma::mat MAT(tmp_mat.begin(), row_size, col_size, false);
       return MAT;
     }


     void operator()(std::size_t begin, std::size_t end)
     {
       for (std::size_t i = begin; i < end; i++)
       {
         for (std::size_t j = 0; j < i; j++)
         {
           // rows we will operate on
           arma::mat MAT = convert();
           arma::rowvec row1 = MAT.row(i);          // get the row of arma matrix
           arma::rowvec row2 = MAT.row(j);

           // compute the average using std::tranform from the STL
           std::vector<double> avg(row1.n_elem);
           std::transform(row1.begin(), row1.end(), // input range 1
                          row2.begin(),             // input range 2
                          avg.begin(),              // output range
                          average);                 // function to apply

           // calculate divergences
           double d1 = kl_divergence(row1.begin(), row1.end(), avg.begin());
           double d2 = kl_divergence(row2.begin(), row2.end(), avg.begin());

           // write to output matrix
           tmp_rmat(i,j) = sqrt(.5 * (d1 + d2));
         }
       }
     }
   };

   // [[Rcpp::export]]
   NumericMatrix rcpp_parallel_js_distance_modify(const Rcpp::NumericMatrix& matrix_input, int N_cores)
   {
     // allocate the matrix we will return
     NumericMatrix matrix_output(matrix_input.nrow(), matrix_input.nrow());
     std::size_t row_size = matrix_input.nrow();
     std::size_t col_size = matrix_input.ncol();

     // create the worker
     JsDistance jsDistance(matrix_input, matrix_output, row_size, col_size);

     // call it with parallelFor
     parallelFor(0, matrix_input.nrow(), jsDistance, matrix_input.nrow()/N_cores);           // parallelFor with grain size setting

     return matrix_output;
    }

    // Example compare: 
    n_row = 1E3;
    n_col = 1E2;
    m = matrix(runif(n_row*n_col), nrow = n_row, ncol = n_col);
    m = m/rowSums(m);

    res <- benchmark(rcpp_parallel_js_distance(m, 6),
            rcpp_parallel_js_distance_orignal(m, 6),
            order="relative")
    res[,1:4];

    #test                                    #elapsed   #relative
    rcpp_parallel_js_distance_orignal(m, 6)  128.069    1.000
    rcpp_parallel_js_distance(m, 6)          129.210    1.009
   ```

As we can see, the datatype within `operator` will be `C++ arma`, and now we can safely and fastly call our user-defined function by directly using the object instead of pointers only, which may not be generic or easily designed.

Now, this `parallelFor` structure will share the same data source without extra copy in parallel computing, and then we can do some slightly change for backtesting by using the idea mentioned in the above question.